# How to do sort in using on particular field

Tags: python, elasticsearch, dsl

I have a document

How to do sort in using  on particular field on elasticsearch

My query is below

```
{
   "sort":{
      "name":"desc"
   },
   "from":10,
   "size":149,
   "query":{
      "match_all":{
         
      }
   }
}
```

I got error

`Text fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document field data like aggregations and sorting, so these operations are disabled by default. Please use a keyword field instead. Alternatively, set fielddata=true on [name] in order to load field data by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can use significant memory.')\"}" }`

My index name is data_new

Below is the code to insert into index

```
test = [   {'id':1,'name': 'Cost Accounting 400', 'professor': ['Bill Cage', 'accounting']},
    { 'id':2,  'name': 'Computer Internals 250', 'professor': ['Gregg Payne', 'engineering']},
    {'id':3,   'name': 'Accounting Info Systems 350',   'professor': ['Bill Cage', 'accounting']},
    {'id':4,'name': 'Tax Accounting 200', 'professor': ['Thomas Baszo', 'finance']},
    {'id':5,'name': 'Capital Markets 350', 'professor': ['Thomas Baszo', 'finance']},
    {'id':6,'name': 'Theatre 410', 'professor': ['Sebastian Hern', 'art']},
    {'id':7,'name': 'Accounting 101', 'professor': ['Thomas Baszo', 'finance']},
    {'id':8,'name': 'Marketing 101', 'professor': ['William Smith', 'finance']},
    {'id':8,'name': 'Anthropology 230', 'professor': ['Devin Cranford', 'history']},
    {'id':10,   'name': 'Computer Science 101',
        'professor': ['Gregg Payne', 'engineering']}]
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
import json
es = Elasticsearch()
es.indices.create(index='data_new', ignore=400)
for e in test:
        es.index(index="data_new", body=e, id=e['id'])
search = es.search(index="data_new", body={"from" : 0, "size" : 2,"query": {"match_all": {}}})
search['hits']['hits']
```

Expected out

- My first Expected output > I need to sort the output with respect to `name` only
- Second Expected  Output > sort with respect to `name` then `id`

How to do the modification on `search = es.search(index="data_new", body={"from" : 0, "size" : 2,"query": {"match_all": {}}})`

I went through the url `https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-sort.html` which is not helping

Comment: I am trying  to sort on name filed

Comment: first answer is helping but Here first its getting sorted in uppercase then lower case. is there any way to apply on both case at one time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you enable `fielddata`, consider why you are using a text field for aggregations, sorting, or in a script. It usually doesn’t make sense to do so.

A text field is analyzed before indexing so that a value like `New York` can be found by searching for `new` or for `york`. A terms aggregation on this field will return a `new` bucket and a `york` bucket, when you probably want a single bucket called `New York`

Instead, you should have a text field for full text searches, and an unanalyzed keyword field with `doc_values` enabled for aggregations, as follows:

```
PUT data_new
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": { 
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": { 
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I guess you can already treat name as keyword using `name.keyword`  like below,

```
GET /data_new/_search
{
  "sort" : [
     { "name.keyword" : {"order" : "asc"}}
  ],
 "from":10,
 "size":149,
 "query":{
   "match_all":{
     
     }
   }
}
```

**See**:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-sort.html

Comment: Here first its getting sorted in uppercase  then lower case. is there any way to apply on both case at one time

Comment: See: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/case-insensitive-sort-doesnt-work/143192/5

Comment: tried with search = es.search(index="data_new", body={
  "sort" : [{"normalizer": "case_insensitive", "name.keyword" : {"order" : "asc"}}],
 "from":0, "size":2, "query":{ "match_all":{}}})

Comment: any idea how to implement how to update my code without change the settings

Answer (score 0):

you can make a PUT request on the index to set fielddata as true:

```
curl --location --request PUT 'http://localhost:9200/index_name/info/_mapping' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
  "properties": {
     "desc": { 
       "type":     "text",
       "fielddata": true
     }
  }
}'
```

where `desc` is the column name

Comment: if i need in ascending order what should i do

Comment: [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-sort.html) will help